# mysql value in array format, convert to PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a part of my application that takes a bunch of values in JavaScript and stores them as an array in my MySQL database.  Example of what this looks like in the database:

```
['123431234','3463412346','235456234','2352351','45623412']
```

When I grab this value in PHP, I can't seem to convert it to a PHP array properly.  What's the proper method to converting a value like this that by default PHP considers a string into a PHP array?

Comment: If it had double quotes instead of single ones, php could [accept it as valid json](https://3v4l.org/P0r5S) (which, of course, it isn't, but it doesn't matter much)

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of your PHP code, what you've tried and what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

> Split a string by string

You can explode your string as following:

```
$pieces = explode("','", $mysql_string)
```

You will then have to clean up the array a bit yourself. You can try [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to clean up any stuff you don't want.

> Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement
>   string

For example:

```
str_replace('[', '', $pieces)
```

Or use an array to find everything you want to replace.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I guess for some reason I was expecting some built-in method. I went ahead and used:
$pieces = str_replace(['"', "'", '[', ']'], '', $arrayFromDatabase);
$pieces = explode(',' $pieces);

Answer (score 0):

If you still can change the way the data is stored, you could think about `json_encode()` and `json_decode()` Which converts data into a well formatted string so it can be converted back easily. If you are communicating with a javascript client anyway, this could make your life much more comfortable.